# C++ TS Concepts and accessors

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

I wanted to use the Concepts TS to help me with data constraining. I will talk about the Concepts discussed in *p0121r0* and I am using GCC 6.2 for the tests.

Take this simple piece of code:

```
template<typename T>
concept bool test_is_available = requires(T t) {
    t.test;
    { t.test++ };
    { t.test-- };
};

template<test_is_available T>
struct Tester
{
    T t;
};
```

I have to pass to the struct Tester a type with the *test* property, which is incrementable and decrementable. Good.

```
struct A
{
    unsigned test;
}

Tester<A> a;
```

Works as expected. Obviously, the following one will not work:

```
struct B
{
    std::string test;
};

struct C
{
    unsigned not_test;
};

Tester<B> b; // error: test++ and test-- are ill formed
Tester<C> c; // error: no test available
```

Now, the real question: why the following one is not working?

```
class D
{
    unsigned test;
};

Tester<D> d; // error: private???
```

I tried to dig into the std paper, but I am not able to understand this behaviour is expected, if the std itself is missing this possibility, if the compiler is not working correctly...

Or maybe I need to declare a sort of friendship, but what could be the point? This is a situation in which the concepts constraints needs not to be *constrained* by accessors...

Any ideas of what is happening here?

**EDIT:**
It is not always easy to give the idea of the problem with a simple example. This one is a bit more complex, but more similar to the real case:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
concept bool Countable = requires(T t) {
    t.counter;
    { ++t.counter };
    { --t.counter };
    //{ t.load(auto&&...) } -> void; <-- I am not sure how to handle this
    { t.unload() } -> void;
};

template<Countable T>
class Scoper
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Scoper(T& t, Args... args) : m_t(&t)
    {
        ++t.counter;
        t.load(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    ~Scoper()
    {
        --m_t->counter;
        m_t->unload();
    }

private:
    T* m_t;
};

class Scopeable
{
public:
    unsigned getCounter() const
    {
        return counter;
    }

//private:
    //template<Countable> friend class Scoper; <-- does not work
    void load(char, int) {}
    void unload() {}
    unsigned counter = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Scopeable scopeable;
    assert(scopeable.getCounter() == 0);
    {
        Scoper<Scopeable> scoper(scopeable, 'A', 2);
        assert(scopeable.getCounter() == 1);
    }
    assert(scopeable.getCounter() == 0);
}
```

As you can see, it is obvious that *counter*, *load* and *unload* have to be private/protected, and that they only has to be accessed from *Scoper*.
If I use an abstract base class I can only constraint *counter* and *unload*, but not *load* (for which, as you can see, I do not know how to handle the correct syntax...).

Maybe this will not change your answers, but the problem is probably a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 10):

This concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept bool test_is_available = requires(T t) {
    t.test;
    { t.test++ };
    { t.test-- };
};
```

requires that `T` have a **publicly accessible** member `test` that is both post-incrementable and post-decrementable.

This type:

```
class D
{
    unsigned test;
};
```

does not have a publicly accessible member test. After all, I cannot write any of those statements:

```
D d;
d.test;   // error
d.test++; // error
d.test--; // error
```

Hence, `D` doesn't meet the concept `test_is_available`. `test` is very much not available.

If you want `D` to be a `test_is_available`, you'll need to make `test` `public`. You can't simply `friend` something, that just breaks the concept system - you'll end up with a `D` that's `test_is_available` to some types but not others. That's not really how things are supposed to work.

Comment: Therefore, you are just saying that there is no way to *ask* for a member, without accessibility restrictions?

Comment: I _think_ you could mark the `Tester` class as a friend and it should provide that private access to the concept as well. I haven't played around with concepts too much though, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Isn't is the same thing we call it `interface` in C#?

Comment: @ar2015 No, they're not the same kind of thing at all. You have to inherit from an interface. In fact, we have interfaces in C++ already - they're just not spelled `interface`: an abstract class with no members.

Comment: I remember once I called in `C#` classes can inherit from the interface and someone immediately corrected me that classes do not `inherit` from interface instead, they `implement` an interface. Interface describes what methods with which quality a class should have. This is more  matter of language design but I feel if `c++` had interfaces a lot of its complexities would be simplified. Abstract classes to me more look like polymorphism vs templates. Comfort vs zero overhead. But in this case, why not a template impose an interface on its parameter?

Comment: @ar2015 Tomato, tomato? C++ _does_ have interfaces. The problem with interfaces is that they're intrusive, I can't have some type I don't own model some interface I need.

Comment: @Barry, I don't get your point about intrusiveness of interfaces.